# org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Path does not exist

Tags: apache-spark

I was having issues trying to read a parquet file stored as a resource in my fat-jar so I tried following code which reads the resource file and copies it onto disk:

```
val inputFile = "test.parquet"
val parquetFile = "/part-r-00000-2185f9a7-ea70-41be-95d2-e9f70f93c43b.parquet"
FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(Main2.getClass.getResourceAsStream(parquetFile), new File(inputFile))
    LOGGER.info("saved resource to external file")
```

This code runs successfully. But when I try to read the file using:

```
spark.sqlContext.read.parquet(inputFile)
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR yarn.ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Path does not exist: hdfs://nameservice1/user/me/test.parquet
```

How can I fix this? I just want to be able to read a parquet file stored as resource in fat-jar. I have tried many things but none of them work.

Answer (score 0):

```
FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile
```

copy Input stream of the file in your Fat jar to local file system not in Distributed file system i.e HDFS.
Try with below code should work

```
spark.sqlContext.read.parquet("file:////<  absolute path of inputFile >")
```